# Stop Photos.app from opening when any device is connected

Tags: photos

I know there are thousands of iterations on this question, but I can't find one dealing with Photos.app from 10.10.3+.

I just want to stop it (or anything else) from opening ever. None of the answers I've found for Image Capture or iPhoto work anymore, as far as I can tell.

To be clear, I know I can go into Image Capture and change the setting per-device, but I am regularly plugging in random devices I've never used before, and I want to turn this behaviour off globally.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest might be to use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) - old but still works on Yosemite & is free.

It installs as a Control Panel, called Default Apps.

Set Media > Camera to 'Ignore'

[image]

I actually set everything to Ignore, I prefer to do these things manually.